# Explaning about terminology about "Render"

Tags: javascript

im a newbie in information technology. Recently, i heard about the term "Render" and i can't understand what it's mean. So, can anyone explain it to me plsss
I also searched and read a lot about it but still couldn't understand it clearly.

Comment: What do you currently understand render to mean?

Comment: render = convert from one format to another.  In graphics, this might be a set of instructions such as "draw a square" "fill in that square" that generates an image.  For web applications, it means taking server-side "code" (the instructions) and generating (rendering) HTML.  To potentially confuse things: the browser then takes that HTML (instructions) and renders it on the display so you can see it as your webpage.  But this is not usually what's referred to as rendering.